# How to add website content translations into Odoo custom theme?

Tags: odoo, translation, multilingual, odoo-14, odoo-website

I have developed custom Odoo(v14) theme. I use this theme for our company website and it is multilingual. Normally I add the translations of the content from Odoo interface but I was wondering if there is a way that I can include them too into my theme. So I can control everything in it. Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use this link to do that.
[Translating Modules or themes Odoo 14](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/misc/i18n/translations.html)